# Python3, allowing user input of " \n " and " ' " characters but replace with " \\n " and " \\' "

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sqlite, python-3.x

Thank you in advance for your assistance...

I am coding an API that will use JSON responses. I am coding in Python 3.5.1. I am allowing the user to type in a predefined message they wish to submit to the Slack chat and Slack syntax uses \n for newlines, so my app will need to allow the user to format their messages using '\n' in their messages but the '\n' naturally is messing up my Python, as it wants to simply make a new line in the sentence instead of printing out that \n which Slack will need to see.

What I figured I would do is simply to .replace('\n', '\\n') so the JSON will still get the intended '\n' and not bother Python. This works fine however I also need to check the user's message for instances of " ' " and replace it with " \\' " so it will not hinder my SQL statement for my database.

I figured I'd make a dictionary and a method to check for instances of certain characters and replace them all at once with their corresponding values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def replace_all(strIn):
    keywords = {"'": "\\'", "\n": "\\n"}
    for a, b in keywords.items():
            strOut = strIn.replace(a, b)
return strOut
```

To test this:
strIn = "You\'re \ngreat at chan\'l \nsurfing don\'t you know?"

When I run my method, I correctly catch the " ' ": " \\' " but the "\n": "\\n" gets ignored. If I perform these as separate strIn.replace("\n": "\\n") and strIn.replace(" ' ": " \\' ") it works.  What am I doing wrong with my method?

Thank you again for your assistance,
Vaylain

---

Updated:

If I do the following it does exactly what I wanted however it is very verbose and not very Pythonic:

```
def checkString(self, strIn):
keywords1 = {"'": "\\'"}
keywords2 = {"\n": "\\n"}
for a, b in keywords1.items():
        pass1 = strIn.replace(a, b)

for a, b in keywords2.items():
        strOut = pass1.replace(a, b)

return strOut
```

Any ideas on how to combine both dicts into one and get the method to work for both without 2 passes over the incoming string?

Comment: "... so the JSON will still get the ..." What? What does JSON need to get? You encode it and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is to escape whole "\n" with "\\n", and when you have "\\n" escape it with "\\\n", I would do something like this:

```
def replace_all(strIn):
    strOut = ""
    keywords = {"'": "\\'", "\\n": "\\\n"}
    for a, b in keywords.items():
        strOut = strIn.replace(a, b)
    return strOut

strIn = "You\'re \\ngreat at chan\'l \\nsurfing don\'t you know?"

print(replace_all(strIn))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I do not control strIn as this is the user's input. I need to check their input and any instance they have entered \n, I need to check and replace it with \\n so it will look like \n to python.

Comment: Well, you didn't mentioned it in question. Now you have 2 options: 

1) Force user to enter valid input
2) Check input after user enter it and correct to valid format

Comment: I need the user to input \n as my API is for Slack.com and they use \n for adding new lines in chat. I want the user to \n like normal, but I must take that \n in the user's message and replace it with \\n so Python will not mess it up. Your suggestion for #2 is what I need to do, only that is my original question...as I do not know how to do this correctly... I need the user to insert \n and I need python to check it and replace \n with \\n, so the \n will still appear in the Slack API...